# java: duplicate class when I try generate JPA static metamodel and use it in Intellij IDE

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have this settings in my gradle script

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceSets.configureEach { sourceSet ->
    tasks.named(sourceSet.compileJavaTaskName).configure {
        options.annotationProcessorGeneratedSourcesDirectory = file("$buildDir/generated/sources/java")
    }
}

idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("$buildDir/generated/sources/java")
    }
}
```

When I start server I get errors like:

```
Error:(9, 17) java: duplicate class: ...domain.entity.Commission_
```

because when server start - creates a folder **out** with copies of my generated classes